# Background Image compressed in Mobile Chrome and Opera

Tags: android, google-chrome, mobile, opera

I'm working on a page for mobile devices and got a sprite as a background Image, which is 13 times higher then the related div-Container. By changing the background Position of this sprite, it looks like an animation. Everything works fine on different iPads (Safari, Chrome, Dolphin), Microsoft Surface and the Sony Xperia Tablet Z (Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Dolphin, Android Ver. 4.3).

I'm also testing my page on an Asus Transformer Prime an a Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1N (Stock browser, Firefox, Dolphin, Chrome, Opera). On this two devices, there's a weird bug in mobile Chrome (Ver. 34.0.1847.114) an Opera (Ver. 21.0.1437.74904). The Android Version of the Samsung Tab is 4.0.4 and of the Asus is 4.1.1.

The wohle Sprite is compressed on the y-axis. Originally, the sprite is 8879px on the y-axis an 1024px on the x-axis large, which is also the background-size of the Div container. While the sprite is compressed, the change of the background-Position works normaly, till the bottom of the sprite reaches the bottom of the div-Container. Then both browser start stretching the sprite when I want to change the background Position. This happens till the background Position reches the value -7770px, then the image just disappears.

Hope someone got an idea what's happening here, I'm totally confused because of it!

Comment: Can you provide a link to a test case or example?

Comment: I've made a jsfiddle, but it doesn't work.. but maybe you see something in the code, which causes the bug: http://jsfiddle.net/pT56P/5/